# GNAT studio 2020 community does not react anymore with GDB Windows 10

Tags: gdb, ada, gnat

I have several ADA projects developing with GNAT studio community version 2020. In some of these projects when I trying to debug, clicking debug results in "Program does not react anymore" when Initializing the debug session. I run the latest version og GNAT Studio and Windows 10 the latest update. With one project GDB does not works anymore since a number of weeks, other projects are still working correct. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your program is not failing at elaboration time?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange since only some of progams affected while other still work correct.

I would try to debug such a program by using only GDB, without GNAT studio to check if problem remains.
It would be also useful to find out if there are any patterns in failing programs, such as: only programs with GUI affected, or only programs with certain compiler flags affected, or programs using certain shared libraries affected.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with running programs from the command prompt on windows 10. So I don't know how to run  GDB from the command prompt.
I have had a similar problem with Thunderbird which for me at random delivers "Program does not react". I have not yet been able to find a common ground within these failures.
In GNAT it s always at the same point after I Click "Debug"in the menu and before I can click "Run"

Comment: It's quite easy. You have GDB in your GNAT installation.
1. Build your program with debugging information
2. Open cmd and navigate to obj folder where compiled program resides
3. Run GDB `C:\GNAT\2020\bin\gdb.exe` <- adjust to your GNAT install path
4. type `target exec main.exe` in GDB console (adjust program name if needed)
5. type `run` in GDB console
6. Check result

Comment: I finaly found the problem. GNAT Studio created for som reason I never dscovered about 4000 breakpoints. These breakpoints costed a lot of time and pure by accident I discovered that after about 10 to 15 minutes the program reacted again